# Selenium cannot locate an element in a small window opened from pressing a button

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver

I'm trying to scrape numbers from a website and Selenium is having some trouble with the final part

[image: T]

After going into the profile of a clinic, I want the code to click this part, after this part is clicked a small window opens up with the number inside.

[image]

the number in this window is a whatsapp link with the class "fs-text-2 whatsapp-click-stats"

following is the snippet of the code I'm using

```
url = "https://infoguia.com/bnom.asp?txt=clinicas&est=100"

# create a new Chrome session
driver = webdriver.Chrome(r'C:\Users\hamxa\Desktop\Chromdriver\chromedriver.exe')
driver.implicitly_wait(50)
driver.get(url)

# get list of clinics on the page
clinics = driver.find_elements_by_class_name("grey-btn-profile.fs-text-button-1.fw-bold")

# loop through each clinic to get its phone number
for clinic in clinics:
  clinic.click() #open detail page for each clinic 
  try:
    # element = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(
    #     EC.presence_of_element_located((By.CLASS_NAME, "fs-text-2.phone-click-stats"))
    # )
    
    whatsapp_button = driver.find_element_by_id('view-whatsapp')
    
    whatsapp_button.click()
    
    # find the number with the class "fs-text-2 whatsapp-click-stats"
    number = driver.find_element_by_class_name('fs-text-2 whatsapp-click-stats')
    # print the number
    print(number.text)
  finally:
    driver.back() # go back to the search results page
    
# close the webdriver
driver.close()
```

and this is the error i'm getting:

```
selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"css selector","selector":".fs-text-2 whatsapp-click-stats"}
```

any ideas on how to resolve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this way,

```
import time
from selenium.webdriver import Chrome
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.wait import WebDriverWait
import selenium.webdriver.support.expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.common.exceptions import NoSuchElementException

driver = Chrome()
driver.get(url="https://infoguia.com/bnom.asp?txt=clinicas&est=100")

clinics = driver.find_elements(By.CSS_SELECTOR, "div.perfil-sec-10-bottom-b-part-2")
links = [link.find_element(By.TAG_NAME, 'a').get_attribute('href') for link in clinics]

for link in links:
    driver.get(link)
    your_element = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, 'div.full-breadcrumb')))
    try:
        driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, 'button[id="view-whatsapp"]').click()
        num = driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, 'a.fs-text-2.whatsapp-click-stats').get_attribute('innerHTML')
        print(num)
    except NoSuchElementException:
        """for those links which don't have WhatsApp number"""
        pass

    time.sleep(1)
```

The idea is that you go to the mail URL and grab the links of all the clinics (here, it's 20). And then you can directly iterate over them to get the WhatsApp number, if any.

output:

```
 (0412)264.2658
 (0426)371.9876
 (0424)154.3403
 (0424)127.5955
 (0412)687.3078
 (0424)577.7972
 (0412)601.6110
 (0412)717.8044
 (0414)819.8567
```